# How can I convert my FLAC music collection to Apple Lossless?

Tags: music, convert

I have a reasonable sized music collection that I keep in FLAC format on my Ubuntu laptop. I'd like to start playing this music on my Mac, and to sync it from there to my iPod. People have suggested that the best way to do this is to convert my collection to ALAC, and I've decided that's what I want to do.

Before I dive in and write custom shell scripts that call `ffmpeg` through some complex `find` command, I thought I'd ask for advice.

How can I best convert my existing FLAC collection to ALAC, without any loss of audio quality and preserving all of the metadata?

Comment: Huh.  I'm surprised.  I thought there'd be an obvious choice for transcoding tool, but all the ones I can find are focused on video.

Comment: What I ended up doing here was writing a custom Python script that called metaflac, ffmpeg and AtomicParsley.

Answer (score 21):

avconv (or ffmpeg, which avconv is a fork of) can do this from the command line:

```
avconv -i input.flac -c:a alac output.m4a
```

It should preserve the metadata by itself.

To do every flac in a directory:

```
for f in ./*.flac; do avconv -i "$f" -c:a alac "${f%.*}.m4a"; done
```

To do every flac recursively (in the current directory *and* all sub-directories):

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*.flac; do avconv -i "$f" -c:a alac "${f%.*}.m4a"; done
```

If you've got the flacs in ogg files or something, obviously change `./*.flac` to `./*.ogg`.

I think this should work with avconv/ffmpeg from the repositories (since ALAC is released under the Apache license, and can be legally distributed), though I have the version from medibuntu installed.

If you want to get rid of the original files, you can put `rm` into the loop. This version uses the `-n` flag for avconv, so it will not overwrite any already-existing ALAC files, and using [`&&` instead of `;`](https://superuser.com/questions/619016/what-is-the-difference-between-command-command-and-command-command) means that if avconv stops with an error then the original FLAC file will not be deleted:

```
for f in ./*.flac; do avconv -n -i "$f" -c:a alac "${f%.*}.m4a" && rm "$f"; done
```

Note that deleting files with rm is irreversible (outside of forensic data recovery), so be careful using it.

Comment: Do you know how to replace the flac files by alac ones, instead of making an alac copy of the flac file?

Comment: @user13 no, avconv/ffmpeg cannot do that, it cannot overwrite the files it uses as input. You could use `rm` to remove the original files, if you wish.

Comment: I'm not really a command line guru (I'm quite new to GNU/Linux), so up to now I used to remove them manually. (nautilus, arrange files by type, and then I can just select al the .flac files in that directory and remove them). I will have a look at how this "rm"-thing works. :)

Comment: @user138 I've edited the answer to show one implementation with `rm` - though do take note of the warning, `rm` is pretty much irreversible, it outright deletes the files rather than moving them to the trash bin. Another alternative would be to use globbing *after* the loop is finished (so you can check that there have been no problems... if the command failed for whatever reason, you wouldn't want to get rid of your originals): `rm -- *.flac` would remove every FLAC in the working directory.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!
I normally keep the original flac files in another directory, so there is no risk of losing them.